# The advantage of empirical likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I saw in a book that one of the advantage of the empirical likelihood is that empirical likelihood regions are range preserving and transformation respecting.

My question is that what is the meaning of range preserving and transformation respecting?

Comment: An estimator is said to be range preserving if its values are confined to the range of what it is to estimate.

Comment: For an increasing function $\phi(x)$, I would call an estimator transformation respecting if $\mathbb P(a \le \hat{X} \le b) =  \mathbb P(\phi(a) \le \widehat{\phi(X)} \le \phi(b))$

Comment: When estimating the prevalence of a disease in a population with results on how many randomly selected subjects test positive (knowing the sensitivity and specificity of the test), the traditional method can give an estimate of prevalence outside the interval $(0,1).$  I suppose that's an example of non-range preserving.